# What does "up-front" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

But he stressed that the Fund had made a big concession by agreeing debt relief would only be decided in 2018, rather than up-front.

source:http://www.cnbc.com/2016/05/24/greece-hopes-to-get-new-loans-cleared-by-euro-zone-creditors.html

Comment: Have you looked up this phrase in a dictionary?  Which aspects of the definition did you not understand?

Comment: I have, and I'm not sure whether it means 1. in this link http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/front_1#front_1__515

Comment: @Rathony: For you, it is too basic but for non-native speakers, I don't think it is.

Comment: @Rathony: The reason why I like posting my questions here is I can get immediate help and I also see that many people posted their questions in the same form of mine (What does... mean?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the debt relief will not be decided **right now**, and will only be decided in 2018.